# How to remove duplicate com from the package name in Android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I have a project and I want to remove duplicate `com` from the package name. 
When I'm clicking on Refactor -> Rename, there is no possibility to delete `com` there. What to do in such situation, how to refactor package name correctly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try changing tree structure from android to project (top left in android studio) and check the folder name of package that you want to change.

Comment: @Rj_Innocent_Coder the same result

Comment: Which package name currently showing in file ?? with double com or single com ??

Comment: com.com.myAppName

Comment: so my advice is to backup the project and change to other temporary name and again change to the name you want, or did you try invalid cache and restart ??

Comment: Name should be the same, just com should be removed, if I will change name, com will stay.

Comment: how are you changing package name ?? by clicking on top folder name of package or the folder with double com ?/

Comment: by clicking on com.myAppName, and then Refactor --> Rename

Comment: you mean by folder which has extra com.. right??

Comment: if yes then try click on top folder of package, from there you change the whole package name, so type com.yourApp and it should change the package

Comment: i assume that you have read the process of changing package name but still this article can help https://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/how-to-change-the-package-name-in-android-studio/

Comment: It's not possible to delete com by such way, because com never appears in the edit area

Comment: That is why i told you take backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove middle package name, I have copied all files from `com.com.myappname` and pasted them to `com.myappname`, after that I deleted middle `com` folder and  changed all places in the code, where I had old package name and to the new package name, these places include: `AndroidManifest, build.gradle` and java files where was mentioned package name, that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Backup your project then open the androidmanifest.xml file:

`package="com.com.companyname.app1"`

[image: manifestfile]

there is a setting in it `package` .. just edit to your liking

EDIT: also, if you're having trouble finding it just open up the project directory tree then search "AndroidManifest.xml" .. it should be in there.  I think most IDEs use this file to store the manifest settings, although different IDEs may place it in different directories.